# what is the url for a *.stackexchange site's api?

Tags: support, api, url-syntax

from my understanding, the documentation suggests that we can use the api against any current *.stackexchange website

what would be the url for the api for one of these ?  e.g. mysite.stackexchange.com

i tried

http://api.mysite.stackexchange.com/1.0/stats

but it just shows a 404 page not found

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`/sites`](http://stackauth.com/1.0/sites) returns all sites in the network.  Valid StackExchange 2.0 sites can be found there, alongside the extant trilogy sites.

Currently, as they are all in beta, they all reside at "somename".stackexchange.com.  As they graduate they will acquire "proper" domains.

Comment: our site was one of the ones before the area51 concept kicked in.  it doesnt appear on that list.  is there a way that the api will be available for our site?  its http://igrad.stackexchange.com

Comment: @DC01 - no, the API is only being deployed for Trilogy and SE 2.0 sites.

Comment: how do we get upgraded to a 2.0 site?

Comment: @DC01 - all 2.0 sites are created through a community process at http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Comment: right, but we dont want to create a new one - how to we upgrade our current one and keep the questions etc? - do we resubmit it in area51?
thanks

Comment: @DC01 - if an SE 2.0 site overlaps considerably with an SE 1.0 site the questions/answers/etc. can be migrated if we think its worthwhile to do so.  Such decisions aren't made until an Area 51 proposal shows it will be entering beta.  Be aware that SE 2.0 sites are community run, and operated by StackOverflow Inc., so ownership of the SE 1.0 content could be an issue.